# How to insert mpdf TOC inside first page?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf, tableofcontents

I am working on PDF generation using the [MPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) library into a Drupal 8 project.

I am planning to put the table of contents (TOC) inside a `<div>` on the first page of my PDF. 
For that, I created a `<tocentry>` tags and put the `<tocpagebreak />` into my `<div>` of the first HTML page.

Unfortunately, the TOC is generated in a new page (i.e., page break is happening before and after the TOC).

How can I generate the TOC within my custom HTML structure and include it into my `<div>`?

Comment: May you copy/past the code you already have (at least the part with MPDF) ?

Answer (score 2):

By default the TOC goes at the bottom, but you can modify its position manually.

In `mPDF`'s docs there's a nice example in which the TOC is before the content:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Introduction');
$mpdf->TOCpagebreak();

$mpdf->TOC_Entry("Chapter 1", 0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Chapter 1 ...');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Notice that `TOCpagebreak()` is invoked before `TOC_Entry` (the function that adds the entry to the TOC) and before `WriteHTML('Chapter 1 ...')`. This latter function adds content to the PDF.

By placing `TOCpagebreak()` before those functions, you make the TOC appear before the contents.

For more details, see [mPDF docs on TOCpagebreak()](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/tocpagebreak.html)